# Iterate through mysql string

Tags: mysql, string, function, iterator, arrays

I want to iterate through a string and store specific values in an array (or array-like thing) depending on the individual characters in that string.

Pseudocode:

```
myArrayThing = [string.length]

Foreach character in string {
    if character is 'b'
       myArrayThing.push(10);
    else if character is 'a'
        myArrayThing.push(5);
    else
        myArrayThing.push(99999);
}
```

What is the fastest way to do that in Mysql?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in sql?  There are much cleaner solutions to this problem if you don't try to use SQL.

Comment: Short answer: yes.
Long answer: it will be far faster to have MySQL do this to 25,000 records than grabbing them, applying the function, and using 10. It will also be way easier to have a MySQL function that I can load into many other databases that will need it.

Comment: Unless your database server is located on mars, I think you'll still find that it doesn't take very long to query 25K records, apply some transformation, then update the database.  I'd even say that it's faster when you factor in the amount of time it takes to write the code.

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I thought I could reasonably do this is something not MySQL, believe me, I would. Circumstances are such, however, that a MySQL solution would quite definitely be the best.